# how to remove subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This query is working fine for me but it is slow , it is fetching record from 2million records, Can you please guide me how can to remove these subqueries and convert it into joins as they are fetching data from same table with different where conditions

```
WHILE @StartDate < @edate
BEGIN
    
DECLARE @startdates  datetime
SET @startdates = @StartDate

DECLARE @edates  datetime 
SET @edates  =  EOMONTH(@startdates)
INSERT into @result      
SELECT *  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT fat.fac_key,
                    fat.fac_name,
                    ISNULL(ROUND(
                        CAST((
                            CAST(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[case]
                                 WHERE cas_response_ts_notification >= @startdates
                                   AND cas_response_ts_notification <= @edates
                                   AND cas_ctp_key = 9
                                   AND cas_cst_key = 20
                                   AND cas_is_active = 1
                                   AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), cas_fac_key) IN (@VALUE)
                              AS FLOAT) 
                            /
                            CAST(NULLIF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[case]
                                 WHERE cas_response_ts_notification >= @startdates
                                   AND cas_response_ts_notification <= @edates
                                   AND cas_ctp_key = 9
                                   AND cas_cst_key = 20
                                   AND cas_is_active = 1), 0) 
                              AS FLOAT) 
                        ) AS FLOAT), 
                        4)
                    ,0) AS month_wise_cwh,
                    ( @startdates ) AS date
            FROM      [dbo].[facility] fat
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].[case] cas ON cas.cas_fac_key = fat.fac_key
            WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), fat.fac_key) IN ( @VALUE )
            GROUP  BY fat.fac_name,
                      cas.cas_fac_key,
                      fat.fac_key
) As result
     SET @StartDate = DATEADD(month,1,@StartDate)
END

  SET @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @facilitiesId, @pos+@len) +1

END
```

Comment: SQL Server optimizer is usually able to produce good query plan either for subqueries or joins. I would think that some of your problems come from expressions like `where convert(varchar(128),fat.fac_key) IN (@VALUE)` - but you need to analyze execution plan; my guess could be totally wrong.

Comment: The subquery isn't the problem, it's the `WHILE`. You're writing SQL, which is a set based language, so you should be using set-based solutions. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Also `convert(varchar(128),fat.fac_key) IN (@VALUE)` has a significant code smell to it. `@VALUE` will be a **scalar** value, so the `IN` might as well be an `=`. Also why are you converting `fat.fac_key` to a `varchar`? They won't help the data engine either.

Comment: @Larnu How about using temp table instead of table variable if there is large amount of data? Does it make sense?

Comment: Using a temporary table, instead of a variable, doesn't address any of the problems outlined above, @Mova .

Comment: You may have to post your table structures. It looks like those subqueries are not even joining to the outer table, so you could do those upfront as single queries into variables and use the variable sin the final query. May make it quicker, but should make it clearer.

Comment: This is not even the full code. There is a single `BEGIN` but two `END` statements. The last line uses variables that are not declared in the given code.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, The changes you have mentioned above should be there. But in addition, does temp table instead of table variable makes sense?

Comment: The whole thing is running inside of a loop. What about that?

Comment: Only if the OP is dealing with 10,000's of rows or more, probably @Mova , due to the assumptions SQL Server makes about Table Variables. Of all the "problems" using a table variable vs a temporary table is likely one of the smallest contributions, if it does at all.

Comment: After reformatting your SQL to make it more readable, that whole "month_wise_cwh" column calculation with its SELECT COUNT(*)s, looks like it would have the same value for each iteration of the WHILE?  That being the case, it could possibly be extracted into a common table expression i.e. some variation of `WITH t1 AS (SELECT ... FROM dbo.[case]...)` so that it doesn't run for every record selected, but just once for each loop iteration (if I understand correctly).